# add_action and remove_action if custom field exists

Tags: custom-field, actions, genesis-theme-framework

I know this may be off-topic as it has to do with Genesis (a premium framework), but with general WordPress, this has to do with running a `remove_action` and an `add_action` depending on if a custom field exists. I'm not seeing something simple that I'm doing wrong here.

What I'm trying to do is show the default breadcrumbs unless a custom fields exists, and if so, display the contents of a custom field.

Why doesn't

`remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
add_action('genesis_before_loop', 'customfield_breadcrumbs');`

fire when a custom field exists, remove the default breadcrumbs, add `customfield_breadcrumbs` and then `echo` my custom field?

**The full function:**

```
function customfield_breadcrumbs() {

global $post;

$crumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', true); 

    if ($crumb) {

remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
add_action('genesis_before_loop', 'customfield_breadcrumbs');

echo '<div class="breadcrumb">';
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', $single = true);
echo '</div>';

    }
}
```

This correctly outputs the html (from $post and $crumb) of the custom field, but I need to display the default breadcrumbs unless there is a custom field:

```
 function customfield_breadcrumbs() {

    global $post;

    $crumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', true); 

        if ($crumb) {

    echo '<div class="breadcrumb">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', $single = true);
    echo '</div>';

        }
    }
```

And this is the core breadcrumb function from Genesis:

```
function genesis_breadcrumb( $args = array() ) {

    global $_genesis_breadcrumb;

    if ( ! $_genesis_breadcrumb )
        $_genesis_breadcrumb = new Genesis_Breadcrumb;

    $_genesis_breadcrumb->output( $args );

}

add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
```

And they are configured by settings in Genesis >> Theme Settings:

[image]

Comment: When are you calling the function? Does `$post` contain expected value and `$crumb` is in turn as expected?

Comment: Rarst, thanks, see edited quesiton. I get the corect values for $post and $crumb But the if statement doesn't remove_action and add_action.

Comment: Are the actions added with priorities in framework code? Those are needed on removal to uniquely identify what is being removed.

Comment: Interesting, I don't know. I just added to my question the core breadcrumb function from Genesis for reference; there are no priority calls in it. So I need a priority?

Comment: *when* do you call `customfield_breadcrumbs`? it seems odd that you're adding an action to call `customfield_breadcrumbs` inside `customfield_breadcrumbs`, not sure how you're expecting that to work.

Comment: @Milo, thanks, well, that's maybe why I'm asking the quesiton :) I don't why adding that action where it is right now doesn't work.

Comment: you still haven't answered *when* `customfield_breadcrumbs` gets called to start this process. adding an action inside the same function you want to trigger isn't going to work.

Comment: customfield_breadcrumbs needs to get called after remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );

Comment: Just as a side note, I was having strange results with "Genesis" breadcrumbs until I realized the site had Yoast SEO handling the breadcrumbs enabled too - it takes precedent. Just in case...

Comment: @songdogtech - I don't think you're understanding my question. the function as you've posted it does nothing on its own. the action that triggers it is inside the function it's supposed to trigger. it's like you've got a horse and a cart, and you've put the horse inside the cart and are asking us why the cart isn't moving.

Comment: @Milo, the breadcrumbs are already enabled by the core Genesis breadcrumb function; I need to unhook them and rehook my own bredcrumb function `customfield_breadcrumbs` if a custom field exists. That's why I'm trying remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
add_action('genesis_before_loop', 'customfield_breadcrumbs'); inside the if statement.

Comment: @PatGilmour, thanks, but there is no Yoast involved.

Comment: @songdogtech we're going in circles here, you're not understanding my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on how your code works as-is, as I mentioned in my comment. It looks like you're adding an action to call a function inside the function that you want to call with that action. If *nothing outside the function invokes it*, it never runs.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_breadcrumb_condition' );

function check_breadcrumb_condition(){
    global $post;
    $crumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', true); 
    if ($crumb) {
        remove_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'genesis_do_breadcrumbs' );
        add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'customfield_breadcrumbs' );
    }
}

function customfield_breadcrumbs() {
    global $post;
    echo '<div class="breadcrumb">';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_breadcrumb', true);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Ah, that works! I didn't know enough to be able to describe what I was trying to do. I now see that the remove and add actions need to be in a separate function called first, before they are modified by customfield_breadcrumbs. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: you might also want to check `is_single()` along with the meta value, otherwise if you visit an archive page where the first post has a custom breadcrumb, you'll get that post's breadcrumb instead of the archive breadcrumb.

Comment: Thanks, good point, and I did that. Genesis also gives options where the breadcrumbs display (I added a screenshot to my question) as to archives, etc.